# Jackson deserialize JSON string with empty string instead of object

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm having trouble deserializing a response I receive from an external api.

Normally the API returns the following JSON :

```
{ 
 "RootObj": {
   "InnerObj" : [
           {"Elem1": "Val1"},
       ]
    }
}
```

That is parsed all fine. However when the API does not find something it returns this JSON :

```
{ 
 "RootObj": ""
}
```

But with that JSON, Jackson cannot deserialize it.. neither can it when you use the deserializeOption ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT.

The JSON does get converted to :

```
{ 
 "RootObj": null
}
```

However, now Jackson cannot instantiate my POJO because of the null pointer. I expected it to create the rootObj class, with the InnerObj set to null..

I've tried all sorts of tactics, like @jsonsetter etc. But I had no luck in doing so. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? Preferably with an objectmapper setting.

Comment: It seems like a bad design they should return `null` instead of empty string and you are telling this property did not helped `DeserializationFeature ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT`

Comment: You said the first chunk of JSON parses fine... but it's invalid JSON? The value of InnerObj is not properly an array nor an object.

Comment: @JeremyHunt correct. That was merely a type error. I wrote the question on mobile :/. Editted.

Comment: show the code how are you deserializing it ? @KevinVanDenBroek